# Limit inventory quantity to X if > X

Tags: liquid

I am trying to limit the inventory shown on the product page to a specific number if above it. E.g:

```
if inventory is < x = display inventory.
if inventory > x = display x

Any advice?

{% if settings.display_inventory_left and variant.inventory_quantity <= settings.inventory_threshold %}
      <div class="inventory_left">
        {% if variant.inventory_management != blank and variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
          {% capture items_left_text %}
            {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 1 %}
              {{ 'products.product.items_left_count.one' | t }}
            {% else %}
              {{ 'products.product.items_left_count.other' | t }}
            {% endif %}
          {% endcapture %}
          {% if variant.inventory_quantity <= settings.inventory_threshold %}
            {{ variant.inventory_quantity }} {{ items_left_text }}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only checking if inventory_quantity is less than or equal to the threshold. You need an else clause which will execute if inventory_quantity is greater than the threshold.

Also, I imagine settings.inventory_threshold is a string which can't be directly compared to variant.inventory_quantity as this is an integer. To cast a string to an integer, you can just apply a maths filter. For example:

{% assign inventory_threshold = settings.inventory_threshold | times: 1 %}

You can then compare inventory_threshold to variant.inventory_quantity.

The following should achieve what you want:

```
{% comment %} Apply maths filter to cast threshold to integer {% endcomment %}
{% assign inventory_threshold = settings.inventory_threshold | times: 1 %}

{% if settings.display_inventory_left %}
  <div class="inventory_left">
    {% if current_variant.inventory_management != blank and current_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
      {% capture items_left_text %}
        {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity == 1 %}
          {{ 'products.product.items_left_count.one' | t }}
        {% else %}
          {{ 'products.product.items_left_count.other' | t }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endcapture %}
      {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= inventory_threshold %}
        {{ current_variant.inventory_quantity }} {{ items_left_text }}
    {% comment %} Else clause to execute when quantity > threshold {% endcomment %}    
      {% else %}
        {{ inventory_threshold }} {{ items_left_text }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```